# Are CIL Instructions atomic?

Tags: .net, multithreading, cil

Does the .Net runtime make any guarantees about the atomicity of CIL instructions? If so, what are they? Are all CIL instructions atomic? Or does it depend on the atomicity of the machine code generated by the JIT compiler and therefore too platform specific to make any guarantees?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The C# spec talks about this, and the same truths essentially apply to CIL too; basically, all the integer types up to 4 bytes are guaranteed atomic, and any *reference* reads/writes are guaranteed atomic.

However, outside that no guarantees are made; `double` is not guaranteed atomic, for example - here `Interlocked` may be helpful.

To quote from [ECMA 335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf) (Common Language  Infrastructure (CLI) Partitions I to VI)

> ### 12.6.6 Atomic  reads  and writes
>
> A conforming CLI shall guarantee that
>   read and write access to properly
>   aligned memory locations no larger 
>   than the native word size (the size of
>   type native int) is atomic (see
>   §12.6.2) when all the write accesses
>   to a  location are the same size. 
>   Atomic writes shall alter no bits
>   other than those written.  Unless
>   explicit layout  control (see
>   Partition II (Controlling Instance
>   Layout)) is used to alter the default
>   behavior, data elements no  larger
>   than the natural word size (the size
>   of a native int) shall be properly
>   aligned.  Object references shall  be
>   treated as though they are stored in
>   the native word size.
>
> [Note: There is
>   no guarantee about atomic update
>   (read-modify-write) of memory, except
>   for methods provided  for that purpose
>   as part of the class library (see
>   Partition IV).   An atomic write of a
>   ―small data item‖ (an item  no larger
>   than the native word size) is required
>   to do an atomic read/modify/write on
>   hardware that does not  support direct
>   writes to small data items. end note]
>
> [Note: There is no guaranteed atomic
>   access to 8-byte data when the size of
>   a native int is 32 bits even  though
>   some implementations might perform
>   atomic operations when the data is
>   aligned on an 8-byte  boundary. end
>   note]

Since `native int` must be *at least* 32 bits, that is the most guarantee it can offer.

Comment: What is meant by a "native int"? An `int` as defined by C/C++? That has a minimum size of 16 bits, not 32. Not that it is relevant to the question, of course. :) +1

Comment: Gotcha. I wasn't aware the CLI spec defined a "native int". :)

Comment: Hmm, am I right in concluding that the additional notes basically imply that there is no absolute guarantee whatsoever (except for reads)? .NET is allowed to to have 32bit int writes not to be atomic on plaforms with int sizes of 64bit and no direct 32bit write capability, right? So it's only a guarantee in the context of a specific platform.

Comment: @John 32-bit int etc are guaranteed atomic in the language spec; 64-bit are not